# How to sum up multi-line of output of numbers?

Tags: bash, ksh

I have a multi-line of output from some shell scripts, one integer number per line. Like:

```
12
11
55
337
11
34
```

Problem is, how could I sum up these numbers with a shell command? I tried `sum`, but it doesn't do what is intended:

```
<some_shell_scripts> |sum
36373     2
```

Any simple solution in ksh or bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe that to awk:

```
<some_shell_scripts> | awk 'NF{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

Answer (score 4):

With `awk` you can make it with something like this line:

```
$ awk '{count+=$1} END{print count}' file
460
```

With `bash`:

```
sum=0
while read number
do
  sum=$(($sum + $number))
done < file
echo $sum
```

Test:

```
$ sum=0; while read number; do sum=$(($sum + $number)); done < file
$ echo $sum
460
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [bc](http://www.basicallytech.com/blog/?/archives/23-command-line-calculations-using-bc.html) for command-line calculations, awk is overkill.

Eg:

```
echo "23 + 23 + 23" | bc
69
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace all the '\n' with '+' by sed and then bc

```
<some_shell_scripts> | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/+/g' | bc
```

Comment: What does the first sed expression mean?

Comment: @QiangXu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n

Comment: Here is what I got: `sed: 0602-417 The label :a;N;$!ba;s/\n/+/g is greater than eight characters`

Comment: @QiangXu What's your input? It is okay here. I just copy the input ,and cat then sed then bc.

Comment: Still same error. Looks it is unrelated to the input, e.g, how many lines of integers, but it may be that my sed version is not the same as yours? `sed --version` doesn't work for me here. But it looks mine is not GNU `sed`. My `sed` comes with the AIX machine.

Comment: @QiangXu my sed it GNU sed version 4.2.1. you can also use other methods to replace '\n' by '+',  for example tr.